# How to modify style properties in an Highcharts tag with Angular?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have this code in the my html page:

```
            <div *ngIf="loading && chartOptionsXrange">
                <highcharts-chart 
                    [Highcharts]="Highcharts" 
                    [options]="chartOptionsXrange"
                    [(update)]="updateFromInput" 
                    style="width: 100%; height: 850px; display: block;">
                </highcharts-chart>
            </div>
```

And I would like to bind the style value with a variable from my component.
I tried this:

```
 [style]="xrange"
```

And in my component:

```
xrange = 'width: 100%; height: 800px; display: block'
```

but it doesn't work.
In fact I would like to adapt the height according to the number of elements to be displayed.

How can it be done?

Comment: Please provide some working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To style element using a JavaScript variable, you could use the `[ngStyle]` directive.

```html
<div [ngStyle]="myStyle">Div styled with the JS</div>
```

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  ...

  myStyle = {
    'height.px': 200,
    'width.px': 200,
    background: 'red',
    display: 'flex',
    'justify-content': 'center',
    'align-items': 'center',
    'color': 'white',
  }
}
```

**Live demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngstyle-showcase?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

However in this case I would recommend another solution. Instead of styling the chart's container, you could just set the chart's height in your `chartOptions`.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;

  heightCondition = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 200 : 500;

  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    chart: {
      height: this.heightCondition
    },
    title: {
      text: `Height: ${this.heightCondition}px`
    },
    series: [
      {
        type: "line",
        data: [1, 2, 3]
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

**Live demo:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-uiq1sn?file=src/app/app.component.ts